# Can't detect star/multiply or comma being pressed

Tags: android

Title is pretty clear i guess.I tried many ways,onKeyListeners,dispatchKeyEvent, onKeyDown...none work for `KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY , KEYCODE_STAR , KEYCODE_COMMA , KEYCODE_NUMPAD_COMMA`.
What's the issue with this ? It's working fine for `ENTER and BACK`.Here are some of the ways i've tried to detect.I'm trying all this on a Nexus 10,if it matters.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        ShowDialog3();
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_COMMA)) {
        EditText eddd = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
        eddd.append(".");
        return true;
    }

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY)) {
        enter();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Another try :

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            enter();

            return true;
        }

    }
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STAR) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            enter();

            return true;
        }

        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_COMMA)) {
            EditText eddd = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
            eddd.append(".");
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

I also tried setting onKeyListener for the edittexts i'm using,didn't work.
What's wrong... ? Is it a bug or some sort ?
Thanks and have a nice weekend !